# Trumba iCal files with multiple calendars

Tags: php, curl, import, icalendar

I'm able to import iCal files to Trumba using the following basic properties:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Company Name//Product//Language
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY: This is a Test Event Title
UID:D70C88D5-E5A1-48EC-84A4-D05DBD5CD8F6-99
DTSTART:20130514T090000
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I'm sending this data via CURL with the url containing the calendar webname.. Is there a property to determine that the event would also show on the other calendars?? How am I supposed to check the boxes of other calendars under "Also Shows On" list???

Currently, I can post events to multiple calendars.. The problem is 1 event that shows on multiple calendars would also appear many times on the same date if their assigned calendars are all checked.. :( How can I prevent same event from appearing twice or more?

Comment: "other calendars" do you know the calendar names?

Comment: Yes.. I know the calendar names (or web names)... Do you know how I should proceed with this @Dagon ? Your help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: you can use the "x-wr-calname" value to specify a calendar by name; leave it iut for the default one.

Comment: @Dagon Isn't that use for displaying the name of the calendar only? Am I able to indicate more than one calendar with that?

Comment: i don't know Trumba, but i can use that to put items in to specific calendars in  outlook.